# How do you say "She looks good in everything" in Japanese

Tags: translation

How do you say "She looks good in everything" (in terms of clothing)? Context is, someone said a certain girl looks like in a certain outfit, to what I'd like to say the above. My first idea was 彼女なら何でも似合ってる but it feels a bit off.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your word choice is already perfect, but you don't need the progressive form (ってる) here (unless you have actually seen her in various types of outfit and want to emphasize that fact). How about:

- 彼女なら何でも似合う。
- 彼女は何を着ても似合う。